# How to Use a reCaptcha token to open a captcha prompt in a different window

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, recaptcha, captcha

I am Using puppeteer to automate filling out a form. although when testing it in `headless: true` I can easily solve the captcha there so it is no problem. The problem is the program MUST be headless so in order to solve the captcha I must bring the captcha to a separate window and solve it there. I see you can grab a Recaptcha token but I don't know how I open a Recaptcha window using that token? Almost like a captcha solving window, I don't know if you have to use a certain library?

[image]

If

Comment: I can't answer the whole question but I can tell you that the services that do this don't use that token, just the sitekey and maybe the page url.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found the answer, if not try using this https://github.com/NoahCardoza/CaptchaHarvester
it a captcha harvester like the ones in sneakers bots, when u solve each captcha a token is generated and u can use it to solve captcha I think