# Open captcha in new window puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, recaptcha

Сan I somehow open the captcha from the crackstation (https://crackstation.net/) website in a new window? I found a similar question on SO: [How to Use a reCaptcha token to open a captcha prompt in a different window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545234/how-to-use-a-recaptcha-token-to-open-a-captcha-prompt-in-a-different-window) Here, roughly speaking, the same question as mine. Does anyone have any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: You don't need the token, just the sitekey, and possibly the url. Just load a page with the recaptcha scripts on it and use the same sitekey.

Comment: @pguardiario And how to do it? Can you describe in more detail if it's not difficult